# Enable query across partitions on Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the .NET Core [Cosmos DB Client NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/) v3.4.4

I need to query across partitions, but I haven't found how to do this like `FeedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery` as described in the following article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container

How do I enable cross partition queries?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cross partition queries are enabled by default in V3.

If you do specify a `PartitionKey` in the `QueryRequestOptions`, it becomes a single partition query.

[Source code reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/e534de251bdadafd1adb960da83c15d463486a66/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/RequestOptions/QueryRequestOptions.cs#L173-L177)

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/731

> The v3 SDK sets the EnableCrossPartitionQuery automatically based on the query and QueryRequestOptions.PartitionKey value. There is no need to set it in v3.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CosmosDB SDK v3 Cross Partition Queries are [`enabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.enablecrosspartitionquery?view=azure-dotnet) by default.

There is no longer "FeedOptions", instead EnableCrossPartitionQuery is set automatically based on the [`query`](https://github.com/bartr/bluebell/pull/54)