# Querying multiple items in Azure Cosmos Db

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Suppose I have a "Employee" container with Partition Key as the "EmployeeId". What is the best way to query multiple employee items from this data store? I am using the .Net SDK V3 of Azure Cosmos Db

The option I could think of is -

Using ARRAY_CONTAINS() - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633950/enable-query-across-partitions-on-microsoft-azure-cosmos-client)

```
Select * FROM Employee e where ARRAY_CONTAINS(@EmployeesIdList, e.EmployeeId)
```

This query will still be a cross-partitioned query. 
Also as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633950/enable-query-across-partitions-on-microsoft-azure-cosmos-client), cross partition queries are enabled by default in the V3 sdk. So is this the correct way to query multiple such items?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to achieve?  Are you trying to pull all documents in the collection, or all documents with a specific EmployeeId, or all documents with one of a defined set of EmployeeId values?  Also, can you post a sample document.

Comment: Use in clause or partition feature to fetch records. Partitions are logical separation in Cosmos DB and are well used for many purposes, one you have mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use IN operator in Azure Cosmos DB to include multiple values and pull data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm813.png

Comment: This link is dead

Comment: It is working for me - I am able to view the image!

Comment: It shows me a message "Access Denied". maybe try from a different machine/browser?